# SQL Sub Query Help

Tags: sql

I am having trouble with a homework question.
Specifically, find the maker(s) who produce(s) a PC faster than all laptops.
The query I am using is

```
SELECT  DISTINCT maker
From Product
Where model = (SELECT model
                        FROM PC 
                        WHERE speed > ALL (SELECT speed
                                             FROM Laptop));
```

However I keep getting an error saying that my sub query is returning more than one row. Is this a syntax error on my part or is my logic just off?

Comment: Woohoo! Someone who openly admits to wanting help with a homework question! +1 for honesty.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic would appear to be off.

This filter clause using a subquery:

```
Where model = (SELECT model FROM PC WHERE speed > ALL (SELECT speed FROM Laptop));
```

must return a single row in order for it to work.

You could try:

```
Where model IN (SELECT model FROM PC WHERE speed > ALL (SELECT speed FROM Laptop));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I completly forgot that comparison operators only work for a single value. DOH! Thanks for the help, now I'm off to start my PERL homework.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can also use **JOIN** and using Join depend on what you are going to do.
For example I want to find the maker who produce(s) a PC faster than all laptops and the model of that pc:

```
SELECT  product.maker , max(product.speed)
From product join pc on product.model = pc.model
Group by product.maker
Having product.speed = max(product.speed)
```

I think it should work !

Answer (score 0):

Try--

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT maker 
From Product 
Where model = (SELECT DISTINCT model 
                        FROM PC  
                        WHERE speed > (SELECT MAX(speed) 
                                             FROM Laptop));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I frogot to mention that we are not allowed to use max, min, avg etc for this homework